# snapshot.ConnectionState always waiting

Tags: dart, flutter

In a `FutureBuilder`, `snapshot.ConnectionState` is always waiting, but the future function completed successfully. While in a different page the same block of code works and the `ConnectionState` transitions from waiting to done.

The future function:

```dart
Future getDoctors() async {
    var res = await http.get(globals.domain + "users/docs/");
    var resBody = json.decode(utf8.decode(res.bodyBytes));

    print(res.statusCode);

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          doctors = resBody;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

The future builder:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
    future: getDoctors(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot);
    }
)
```

Actual result:
`AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)`
Expected result: transiton to  `AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.done, null, null)`

EDIT1:
while debugging noticed that the future function `getDoctors()` is called periodically, I guess that's why the snapshot is always waiting

Comment: can you show how you use them in both pages ?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim
it's the same in both pages, and the future function is also similar

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getDoctors(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot);
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return Center(...);
            }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Calling `setState` causes the widget tree to be rebuild. Therefore, when the `FutureBuilder` is rebuilt, the `getDoctors()` function is invoked again, causing an infinite loop (`getDoctors()`->`setState()`->rebuild->`getDoctors()`...)

The solution is to either remove `setState` from the `getDoctors` method or invoke `getDoctors()` once in the `initState()` method, store the `Future` and pass it to the `FutureBuilder`, thus ensuring that it is only done once.

```
Future _doctorsFuture;

initState() {
    ...
    _doctorsFuture = getDoctors();
}

.
.

// Somewhere in build()
    FutureBuilder(
        future: doctorsFuture,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot);
        }
    ),
```

Comment: what is i don't want to stateful widget i.e. initState?

Answer (score 5):

You need to return the value from the Future to finish the connection. Change your Future to something like this:

```
Future<dynamic> getDoctors() async {
    var res = await http.get(globals.domain + "users/docs/");

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        return json.decode(utf8.decode(res.bodyBytes));
    }

    return null;
}
```

And change your FutureBuilder to this:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: getDoctors(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        print(snapshot);

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
            return Center(...);
        }

        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
)
```

*Please modify to match your variables and classes.*

Comment: it transitions to done then goes back to waiting again, the weird thing is it is working on another page

Comment: it keeps printing the snapshot periodically
and it keeps printing everytime it connects to the URL.
does that mean the future function is called periodically?

Comment: This will fix the problem but not for the reasons stated.

Comment: FIrebase reason. set index

Answer (score 2):

Change the return of the Future like:

```
`Future<String> getDoctors() async{
     var res = await http.get(globals.domain + 'users/docs/');
     var resBody = json.decode(utf8.decode(res.bodyBytes));
     if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        if (mounted) {
           setState(() {
               doctors = resBody;
           });
        }
     }
 }`
```

and the FutureBuilder:

```
`FutureBuilder(
    future: getDoctors(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
       switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            break;
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return CircularProgressIndicator(
                       color: Colors.black54,
                       strokeWidth: 2,
                   );
          case ConnectionState.active:
             break;
          case ConnectionState.done:
             return Container(/*here write your return code*/);
       }
    return Text('Some error ocurred try getDoctor');
  },
);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently. This may be a no brainer for some, but maybe you're stuck for the same reasons I was, so I hope this helps!

I had a sign-in screen which required the user to enter their phone number. This was a StatefulWidget with a FutureBuilder that determined the user's dial code based on their current location (so they don't have to enter it in manually before entering their phone number).

IF the ConnectionState is WAITING, the user sees a CircularProgressIndicator, ELSE they see the phone number login widget. Simple.

```
class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInScreen({super.key});

  ...
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  late Future<void> _dialCodeAndCountry;
  String _country = ...;
  String _dialCode = ...;

  Future<void> _getDialCodeAndCountry() async {
    ... await ...
    setState() {
      _country = ...
      _dialCode = ...
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dialCodeAndCountry = _getDialCodeAndCountry();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _dialCodeAndCountry,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          return PhoneNumberLoginForm();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

When a user reloaded the app, the app would function as expected. When a user signed out, they would be taken back to the SignInScreen.

However when the user navigated to the SignInScreen, despite the future completing without any errors, the ConnectionState would hang on WAITING.

SOLUTION:
It turns out that the problem was that SignInScreen widget was being returned within a parent widget, rather than being pushed onto the navigation stack.

```
// NOT WORKING: Returning the widget from within a parent widget:
class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SignInScreen();
  }
}

// WORKING: Pushing the widget onto the navigation stack instead of
// returning it from within another widget:
void _signInScreen() {
  Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => const SignInScreen(),
  ),
);
```

}